# Как найти строку в CSV и удалить ее?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Есть CSV файл примерно такой структуры:

```
000000000,Ivan,test
000000000,Ivan,test test test
000000000,Ivan,column
000000000,Ivan,bla bla bla
000000000,Ivan,oops
000000000,Ivan,take it
000000000,Ivan,start
```

Мне необходимо найти строку со значением, к примеру "oops", после чего скопировать значение этой строки в переменную, а саму строку из CSV удалить. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: С чем конкретно у вас возникли сложности? Приведите в вопросе ваши попытки решения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
input = open('f.csv', 'rb')
output = open('s.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)
for row in csv.reader(input):
    if row[2] != 'oops':
        writer.writerow(row)
input.close()
output.close()
```

f.csv - файл с таблицей

s.csv - файл в котором будет та же таблица но без строки с "oops"